python/dash/plotly Updating a figure does not work
I am trying to create two linked plots. When you click a point in the fig_overview plot, the fig_detail plot should change to show a specific view for that.
To my eyes, I have followed this tutorial to the letter. The first plot and the initial dummy plot show up as expected. Unfortunately, the second figure does not update.
The code is running in WSL on Python 3.10.12, jupyterlab 4.1.8, dash 2.17.0.
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
DASH_THEME = dbc.themes.SOLAR
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

def fig_overview(data):
    n = 30
    fig = px.scatter(x=np.random.random((n,)), y=np.random.random((n,)))
    return fig


def fig_detail(data, task):
    n = 30
    fig = px.scatter(x=np.random.random((n,)), y=np.random.random((n,)))
    return fig

app = Dash('prrdash', external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SOLAR])
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(id='fig_overview', figure=fig_overview(None)),
    dcc.Graph(id='fig_detail', figure=fig_detail(None, None))
])

@app.callback(
    Output('fig_detail', 'figure'),
    Input('fig_overview', 'clickData')
)
def select_project(clickData):
    if clickData is not None:
        fig = fig_detail(None, None)
        return fig

app.run(debug=True)

What I have tried so far:

Verifying the task extraction logic: I can print(task) inside select_project() and get the expected result.
Verifying the plot generator fig_detail(): I can even do fig.show() inside the callback and get the expected result.
Vary mode and jupyter_mode of app.run().
Vary the layout. The code already shows the stripped down version of the DOM.
Vary the ids - that shows you how stumped I am. No, changing the names does not change anything.
I do have a work-around: wrapping the diagram in an additional div and replacing its children with a whole new dcc.Graph does work as intended. But I really would love to understand why this simplified approach fails!

Do you have any suggestions for what to try next? Or even just a little pointer on how to debug.
(EDIT: provided full working code example)

it is kind of hard to know as not all of your code is here so it is not clear what is not working
are you running the dash app in debug mode adding breakpoints where you think it is not working as it should
if you will provide the full code and a mockup data with an expected results I will try to answer it

maybe better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run.

I'm not sure but code in documentation doesn't use figure= in dcc.Graph( figure=fig_detail(data, None)

I used your code to created minimal working code and when I run it with app.run(debug=True) then it shows me error message in browser - it can't update figure. Problem makes ['customdata']. But I don't have all your code.

Thank you for the feedback! I have updated the question to include an mwc. I wasn't aware of debug, so I added that too.
In this example I would expect the lower graph to change (because of new random data) whenever I click a point in the upper.
Alas, no luck, and no errors either.

I didn't have full code so I had to create own version.
And I run it with app.run(debug=True) to see problems
First (in browser) it shows me problem with ['custom']
but I don't have your data and code so you may not have this problem.
It seems problem can be what select_project returns.
If there is no clickData then it (automatically) runs return None
but if I return fig then code works for me
def select_project(clickData):
    if clickData is not None:
        print(clickData)
        task = clickData['points'][0]['customdata'][0]
        fig = fig_detail(data, task)
    else:
        fig = fig_detail(data, None)

    return fig  # <-- it has to always return figure


Minimal working code with random data directly in code
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
import plotly.express as px
import random
import pandas as pd

SIZE = 30

random.seed(0)
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': range(SIZE),
    'y': [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(SIZE)],
    'size': [random.randint(1,5) for _ in range(SIZE)],
    'color': random.choices(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black', 'white'], k=SIZE),
})

def fig_overview(data):
    fig = px.scatter(data, x="x", y="y", size="size", color="color")
    return fig
    
def fig_detail(data, task):
    #print('task:', task)
    
    if task:
        point = task['x']
        temp_data = data[point-1:point+2]
    else:
        temp_data = data
        
    #print('temp_data:', temp_data)

    fig = px.scatter(temp_data, x="x", y="y", size="size", color="color")
    return fig

app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(id='fig_overview', figure=fig_overview(data)),
    dcc.Graph(id='fig_detail',   figure=fig_detail(data, None))
])


@app.callback(
    Output('fig_detail', 'figure'),
    Input('fig_overview', 'clickData')
)
def select_project(clickData):
    if clickData is not None:
        #print(clickData)
        task = clickData['points'][0]#['customdata'][0]
        fig = fig_detail(data, task)
    else:
        fig = fig_detail(data, None)
        #return None  # <--- if I use it then it stop working but it doesn't show error

    return fig  # <-- it has to always return figure


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


EDIT:
Dash has also special method to inform that you don't want to update data - you have to raise error PreventUpdate()
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

@app.callback(
    Output('fig_detail', 'figure'),
    Input('fig_overview', 'clickData')
)
def select_project(clickData):
    if clickData is not None:
        task = clickData['points'][0]#['customdata'][0]
        fig = fig_detail(data, task)
        return fig

    raise PreventUpdate()

Doc: Advanced Callbacks | Dash for Python Documentation | Plotly
Doc also shows that you can use no_update to skip some value in output
from dash import no_update

@app.callback(
    Output('fig_detail', 'figure'),
    Input('fig_overview', 'clickData')
)
def select_project(clickData):
    if clickData is not None:
        task = clickData['points'][0]#['customdata'][0]
        fig = fig_detail(data, task)
        return fig

    return no_update

All this because system may execute this function automatically at start (even if you don't select element in first plot).

Thank you for the detailed answer!
The callbacks are called with empty clickData initially and also shortly after each click.
I don't really understand why they behave that way, but I have to take that initial "if".
Thanks a lot!

I think it may run select_project in some other situations (which it doesn't show to user) and it always expect  the same type of result - fig. I'm not sure but Dash may have some special function which should be use when you don't want to return any value. (or maybe it was in other module)

I found it - it is raise PreventUpdate(). I added it to answer.
